# Is there another way than using patterns to manage state ? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, state

I have been developping a small "days left before an event" Flutter app for myself.

The main page consists of a list of "**Events**" widgets and infos about them.
[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwfIB.jpg)

On the right side of any "Event" there is a bin icon that simply sends an SQL query to delete the event from the DB on tap.

Unfortunately I have been encountering troubles refreshing the main page after the tap on the bin icon because I have no reference of the state of the main page in the "Event" widget.

I have resolved the problem by creating a refresh function in my main page state :

```
void refresh() {
  setState(() {});
}
```

and sending a reference --> **"var hp"** of the state of my main page to the "Event" widget:

```
class Event extends StatefulWidget {
  String title;
  DateTime date;
  int id;
  String daysLeft;
  Color daysColor;
  var hp;

Event(this.hp, this.title, this.date, this.daysLeft, this.daysColor,
      [this.id]) {
    if (this.title == null) {
      this.title = "No title";
    }
  }
...
```

thus, I can refresh my main page when tapping on the bin icon :

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  db.deleteEvent(widget.id);
                  log("refreshing page inc...");
                  widget.hp.refresh();
                  log("refreshed");
                },
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                      size: 30,
                    )))
```

I am aware that this looks super ugly. Moreover, the state of the main page being a private class, I had to store it in a "var" which I do not like.

Is there any other way to do that kind of things ? This all looks super complicated and not really smooth to implement.

I have done some researches and it seems there are a few state management patterns (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options?fbclid=IwAR2yiPjh_jPQKb9s3-2nBYRQwbQmhyv_6tjnZTqbpRbdJOZJdyDFy9HZ07E)

But is there no other way than implementing pattern to do this ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh a widget tree depending on one Variable, you could use a ValueNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder.

A ValueNotifier is like a storage for one Variable. If you update the ValueNotifier's value ( it's variable ) , every ValueListenableBuilder that listens to this Notifier gets rebuilt.

Example:

```
ValueNotifier<String> exampleNotifier = ValueNotifier<String>("Hello World");
/* This declares the Notifier. 
It can be of any type you choose. 
In the parenthesis you have to provide a declaration value. /*
```

Then you have to setup the ValueListenableBuilder.

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
    listenable: exampleNotifier, // Here you have to put in your Notifier
    builder: (BuildContext context, String valueOfNotifier, Widget foo) { // You have to provide a Widget in this builder, I dont really know why, however just not using it does the trick.
        return Text(valueOfNotifier);
    }
)
```

This code will cause the Text-Widget to automatically rebuild everytime the Notifiers value is changed. You update it's value like this:

```
exampleNotifier.value = "Hello World 2";
```